# Как скрыть флаги при компиляции?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

При компиляции проекта для каждого файла используется безумное количество флагов.

Как сделать, чтобы эти флаги во время компиляции не выводились на экран?

К примеру, хочу оставить только путь к компилируемому файлу и результат его компиляции. 
В make-файле команда для цели, как  понимаю, вся выводится на экран. Проект написан на C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Какой бы не был makefile, но там в конечном счете должен быть вызов компилятора. Если перед этой сторокой добавить `@`, то эта строка не будет выводиться. Теперь перед этой строкой достаточно вставить `@echo gcc $@` или что то  подобное и будет "красивый вывод". Аналогично и с линковкой.